# Angular 2 Dynamic Component with Dynamic HTML

Tags: angular

Could you please help me how I can create a dynamic component from a dynamic HTML. What I want is to generate the HTML in real time from the server using service and then embed that HTML in view. I also need data binding on dynamic HTML.

Comment: Hello user and welcome to StackOverflow. This is a place to help coders in **errors in code**. It is not a place for free coding services. If you want help you should post some of your code, what have you tried, and then ask. [I hope this helps you to reformulate your question,](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) and have a nice day.

Comment: This can be done with dynamically creating components at runtime and compiling them like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960